# Angular js, on ng-change how to update options of other select control

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

On change of year value I want to change options of Make drop down, but not getting how to update options of other control.

Below is my plunker with form.
https://plnkr.co/edit/aV65Nab9U9I6YlK2g4sY?p=preview
`api.php` is server response these options should display in Make drop down on change of year.

**autoQuoteCtrl.js**

```
$scope.updateMakeList = function(){
}
```

**index.html**

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="PC">{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._text}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select ng-change="updateMakeList" custom-required="true" ng-options="ans._value as ans._promptText for ans in questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._answerOptions" ng-model="answers.VehicleYear" ng-required="queObj._required" class="form-control {{queObj._pageAttributes.cssclass}}" name="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" id="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" data-que-obj="questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData" select-control-dir setMake custom-required></select>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                    <span class="form-error" ng-show="submitted && DTOstep1.VehicleYear.$error.required">This field is required.</span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this function in your controller -

```
    $scope.updateMakeList = function(name)
                    {                
// Your logic to change value in Make dropdown
$scope.questions[name].VehicleMake.QuestionData._answerOptions = [{'_value':"test",'_promptText':"Test"}];
                    }
```

And update your HTML (year select box)-

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="PC">{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._text}}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <select ng-change="updateMakeList($state.current.name)" custom-required="true" ng-options="ans._value as ans._promptText for ans in questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._answerOptions" ng-model="answers.VehicleYear" ng-required="queObj._required" class="form-control {{queObj._pageAttributes.cssclass}}" name="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" id="{{questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData._attributeName}}" data-que-obj="questions[$state.current.name].VehicleYear.QuestionData" select-control-dir setMake custom-required></select>
                </div>                    
            </div>
```